# Finding if a file name with specific letters exist in azure blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am saving pdf files in azure blob storage and the names of the files are generated dynamically. The file name is in format

```
assessmentLogId + "_" + DateTime.Now.Month + "." + DateTime.Now.Year + "." + DateTime.Now.Hour + "." + DateTime.Now.Minute + ".pdf"
```

where assessmentLogId is an integer. I want to find all files in blob storage that begins with assessmentLogId value. Is it possible to find that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could do it with ListBlobs method of CloudBlobContainer object.